# How do i deactivate security permission on my Local disk?

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I've accidentally changed permissions on my local disk in the *Properties → Security* window and now I can't access my files. How do I restore correct permissions?

Comment: What exactly have you changed? Have you tried to revert it?

Answer (score 0):

Open a command window with elevated privileges (type "cmd" into the start menu search, right-click on cmd an choose "run as administrator").
type "secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose" and hit Enter.
All security permissions should bereset to default.
Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313222

If this does not do what you had in mind, you can change the file/folder owner and/or permissions in the Properties->Security Tab.
Detailed description here: http://www.blogsdna.com/2159/how-to-take-ownership-grant-permissions-to-access-files-folder-in-windows-7.htm

If nothing works, your last option could be a system restore, to a point before you did the changes.

Comment: A system restore should _never_ be performed for this, as it's not required and will likely not solve the issue.  Either the two aforementioned options should be used, or `icacls`.